# Why does Solr 6.1 turn JSON single values into arrays?

Tags: solr

I'm in the process of upgrading from 4.7 to 6.1. I was specifying fields in solrconfig.xml previously but wanted to move to the managed schema way so I can add JSON with new fields whenever I want to.

The problem is 6.1 managed schema is turning string values or numbers etc into arrays. This errors out sorting since Solr cannot sort on array values and its turning my single-value dates into arrays with a single value.

SolrConfig.xml 6.1 has this:

```
<processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
    <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
  </lst>
</processor>
```

I tried making the data types singular such as `strings` -> `string` but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Fields already created are the issue

(sorry to answer my own question but I found out the answer before anyone else did)

Changing the above snippet to singular data types works BUT...

If you have already created fields dynamically with a different solrconfig.xml then you reload it to have singular fields, the defaults will work as expected BUT you have already defined the existing ones.

To remedy this, unloaded the core, deleted it, recreated it, changed the solrconfig.xml to the desired settings, then added the docs in there.

It worked fine after that.

**UPDATE**

I recommend editing the `manage-schema` file found in `/var/solr/data/CORE_NAME/conf` and predefine the fields you want leaving the default behavior. You can also do this through the admin interface by adding fields.